# Error in 1 | country : operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Tags: r

I have imputed missing data using mice, and runs the first multilevel model (empty model):

```
tom <- with(imputer, lm(attitude ~ 1 + (1 | country)))
```

But, I get the following error:

> Error in 1 | country :
> operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

Country is a character variable. I have tried to set it as.factor, but this creates another type of error.. What can the problem be?

Comment: the `(1| country)` syntax doesn't work with `lm` (and, `lm()` doesn't fit multilevel models anyway). Did you mean to use `lme4::lmer()` ?

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I managed to create an empty model using lme4::lmer. However, when I try to get a summary, or icc, I get errors. 

tom <- with(imputer, lmer(attitude ~ 1 + (1 | country)))
summary(tom)

Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod

icc(tom)

Error in !insight::model_info(model)$is_mixed : invalid argument type
In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'icc' is deprecated.
Use 'performance::icc()' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
2: Could not access model information.

Comment: do you have any idea why, @BenBolker?

Comment: try loading the `broom.mixed` package?

Comment: Just get the message that broom.mixed is not available for R version 4.0.0...

Comment: I'm surprised. It looks fine on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom.mixed/index.html