# Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod

Tags: r, lme4, anova, r-mice

I have imputed missing data using `mice`, and now run the first multilevel model:

```
m1 <- with(imputer, lmer(attitude ~ income + (1 | country)))
summary(m1)
```

From the summary function, I get this error:

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod

Moreover, when I use the anova function, I get this error:

> Error: No glance method for objects of class lmerMod

What is causing this error?

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: Try with `library(broom.mixed);summary(m1)` (author of the package commented above)

Comment: OP commented in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309374/error-in-1-country-operations-are-possible-only-for-numeric-logical-or-comp?noredirect=1#comment120727888_68309374) that they were having trouble installing `broom.mixed` under R 4.0.0.  Possibly a transient problem because broom.mixed was updated recently, package binaries may be in the process of being replaced?  Try `install.packages("broom.mixed", type = "source")` ...

Comment: It worked installing the broom.mixed package now, and summary function works also, thanks a lot :-)